# Android Spring Button

Tags: java, android, spring, android-studio, button

How to achieve springs effect on button in Android Studio. So that it decreases and increases when you push it. I have done many searches before posting this question, but could not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a resource file of type animation. Then inside the xml add the following animation (spring.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromXScale="0.5"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```

this will make the button go from half size to full size in 2,5 seconds. If you want a spring effect you'll need a helper class. For many of my programs I've used the following:

```
class MyInterpolator implements android.view.animation.Interpolator {
    private double mAmplitude = 1;
    private double mFrequency = 10;

    MyBounceInterpolator(double amplitude, double frequency) {
        mAmplitude = amplitude;
        mFrequency = frequency;
    }

    public float getInterpolation(float time) {
        return (float) (-1 * Math.pow(Math.E, -time/ mAmplitude) *
                Math.cos(mFrequency * time) + 1);
    }
}
```

if you want to set the animation programmatically use the following method on your button:

```
public void springView(View view) {
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Animation myAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.spring);

    MyInterpolator interpolator = new MyInterpolator(0.1, 10);
    myAnimation.setInterpolator(interpolator);

    button.startAnimation(myAnimation);
}
```

Depending on how spring-y you want that button, increase the values inside the new MyInterpolator(0.1, 10).